# Java - Import class from another package in a different directory

Tags: java, import, package

I have arranged my project as follows:

```
myProject  
¦  
¦---Directories  
¦   ¦  
¦   ¦--ArrayDirectory.java  
¦   ¦--ArrayListDirectory.java  
¦   ¦--HashMapDirectory.java  
¦   ¦--Directory.java  
¦  
¦---Other  
    ¦  
    ¦--Entry.java  
    ¦--Inputter.java
```

All the classes in the Directories file have `package directories;` at the top, and those in Other have `package other;`

Currently, in all the classes in Directory, I am trying to use the class Entry using `import other.Entry;` but this is giving the compilation error "package other does not exist".

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong: package names?, file structure?, import statements?

Comment: Instead give the packages single names, eg «PackageA», «PackageB»

Comment: Still get the same problem

Comment: Firstly, java naming convention is that package names (and so associated directories as well) be all lower-case.   Package names would not include the directory-name where the project is located (ie, try having the `package` and `import` statements not including `myProject` or `Project2` )

Comment: I've changed to what you suggested, but now I still have the same problem

Comment: How (ide/terminal) are you compiling your code?

Comment: Compiling using javac in terminal